# pcolormesh limit values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a matrix M whose values are between 0 and 10. I would like to plot it using the color scheme:

```
plt.pcolormesh((M), shading='auto', cmap='twilight')
plt.colorbar()
```

but plotting in different colors (eg. red and black) all the values that higher than 8 (resp. lower than 2)
How can I use pcolormesh to do so?

Comment: You can check the documentations of `pcolormesh` (look for `vmin` and `vmax`) and `colorbar` and find the answer yourself. Please do post the answer here, so others can refer to it.

Comment: so far I have been able to use the ends of the color scheme as upper and lower limit with `plt.pcolormesh((M), shading='auto',vmin=liminf,vmax=limsup)
plt.colorbar(extend = 'both')
` How can I set specific colors for the ends?

Comment: Sorry, you need the `Colormap` docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
my_cmap = plt.get_cmap(name='viridis', lut=None).copy()
my_cmap.set_under('k')
my_cmap.set_over('y')
plt.pcolormesh((M), shading='auto',cmap=my_cmap,vmin=2,vmax=8)
plt.colorbar(extend = 'both')
```